# Combining Sumif, Sum & Filter

Tags: google-sheets

I have a huge form responses spreadsheet indicating what parts my engineers have used. The 2 formulas below I have created below work as intended individually, is there any way of combining them together to return the sum of parts used which is column D for an engineer for a given month?
B2 is the engineer from list & C2 is the date.

=SUMIF($B$5:$B6414,B2,$D$5:$D$6414) returns total for named engineer for all months
=SUM(FILTER($D$5:$D$6415, MONTH($C5:$C$6415)=C2)) returns total for month for all engineers

Comment: Try share your sample data to have better idea how to address it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking for when you say "combine" (i.e., what the composite formula should be returning). But logic tells me that you may just be trying to return the total for one named engineer (B2) for one given month (C2). If that is correct, try this:

`=SUM(FILTER($D$5:$D$6415, $B$5:$B6415=B2, MONTH($C5:$C$6415)=C2))`

Comment: Hi, I have managed achieve what I needed using =ArrayFormula(sumifs(D5:D,B5:B,B2,month(C5:C),C2))

Comment: Great. Always keep in mind that we can only make suggestions based on what you share with us. Your posted original formula showed locked ranges (with the $) running only through row 6415, so we can only assume that you meant to do this (e.g., that perhaps there was other data running 6416 and down, etc.). The more you share, the more fine-tuned suggested solutions can be. Seeing your final formula, mine could have been =SUM(FILTER(D5:D,B5:B=B2,MONTH(C5:C)=C2)). There is no performance benefit of one over the other (and there is often more than one way to achieve the same goal).

Comment: Thanks Erik, appreciate your comments.